# Is there a way to update a cloud app instead of redeployed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I was starting Windows Azure using `WebSites`, now I'm facing with the situation where I need `Crystal Reports` in my site, so I'm looking for a way to install the Redistribute Files to use it in my web page to generate reports.

I follow this page:

http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/07/running-crystal-reports-on-windows-azure

So instead of having a simple website, I'm gonna use a cloud app. Unfortunately, I'm updating frequently my website (role in Windows Azure project).

Do I need to redeploy all the time my cloud app each time I update my MVC project? Because it takes so long (like an hour, because I included a msi installer)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you build some custom extensibility into your application with some very robust dependency injection, yes, you have to redeploy.

Comment: What you do think I can do? I mean, I need speed to update my MVC4 project (WebRole) and the cloudapp to have CrystalReports runtime. I can't find another suggestions :(

Comment: Are you using **Web Sites** or **Web Roles**? I see you posting conflicting info on this point and this is important.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After re-reading your question again, I realised that you're using Windows Azure Websites.

The correct way to accomplish this is to use a webrole rather than the Websites

What you need to do is to store the installer as a blob in Cloud Storage.

Then part of a Azure Startup Task you can download from the blob and execute the installer.

If possible, you can also use the WebPICmdline (i.e the Web Platform Installer Commandline) to download and install for you from the Startup Task.

Steve Marx has done a few posts on using Azure Startup tasks. Here is one of them http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit to @Robert's answer: If the *actual execution* of the MSI is taking an hour, then this is not a very good use case for web/worker roles. Anything that takes more than a few minutes doesn't really fit well with the stateless scalable model. If that's the case, you should consider running a Virtual Machine for running Crystal Reports. Then you can use your web role for everything else.

If, on the other hand, the one-hour time is mostly consumed by the uploading of the MSI, then I'm completely in alignment with Robert: Store the MSI in a blob, and then download it to your role instances upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split your single Cloud project into two - one for Crystal Reports only. This way you can deploy it separately from MVC site. You could also build extra smarts into start up task, maybe checking if Crystal is already installed. However, I think splitting them up should be good enough for you

Answer (score 0):

Normally the update process does not lead to an complete re-image of your webrole, only the approot gets destroyed! Here you can find a very detailed information about what is happening on update and deployment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh472157.aspx

What does that mean to your problem? Code deployment is an "in-place update" process. If you install Crystal Reports in Drive C: or D: it wont get destroyed on each deployment.

In your Start-Up Task you have to check, whether the software is already installed, or not. In case it is not installed, just install it, as mentioned above on Drive C: or D:

Edit: I got the Point: Does your update Process takes so long, because of the file-size of your MSI? If so, i also suggest to upload the MSI into Blob-Storage.